# Did Jesus die for our sins?

Tags: life-of-jesus

I don't get this part.

Did Jesus die for our sins so that we could sin as much as we want to?

And if so, why is it a sin to eg. lie, steal, cheat, if Jesus already died for us so that we could sin?

Comment: Please consider speaking to your pastor for clarification on this question.  Unfortunately this isn't an appropriate place to ask it - as we have no authority to answer.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). What you're going to find is that we are an academic site here, and that while this is a very good question, it really isn't an academic one.  Theologians will get wrapped around the axel on anti-nomianism (a term you could look up), Satisfaction Theory, and General vs. Limited Atonement.  You really want to understand what grace is - and that is really better had in a one-on-one conversation.

Comment: Romans 6:1 - "What shall we say then ? Are we to continue in sin so that grace may increase ?  2 May it never be! How shall we who died to sin still live in it?  3 Or do you not know that all of us who have been baptized into Christ Jesus have been baptized into His death ?  4 Therefore we have been buried with Him through baptism into death, so that as Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the Father, so we too might walk in newness of life." These verses say it all. Christ died not only to forgive our sins, but also to give us the desire and the power to defeat sin. Don

Comment: A little bit related [If there were no punishment for sin would salvation be necessary?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/23206/if-there-were-no-punishment-for-sin-would-salvation-be-necessary)

Answer (score 3):

No, Jesus did not save us so we can sin as much as we want to.  In fact, the actual consequences of sin are temporary pleasures and lasting pain.  Why, then, would Jesus want us to incur greater amounts of lasting pain?  Sin is always to our loss, perhaps not always physically, but we are not merely physical beings.  We are spiritual beings, so the spiritual consequences of sin are always to our loss.

The epistles are mostly instructions for holy living, and holy living is what we are saved to.  We are saved from sin and its penalty, but we are also saved to something.

> For God has **not called us for the purpose of impurity**, but in sanctification.  1 Thessalonians 4:7 NASB
>
> But like the Holy One who called you, **be holy yourselves** also in all your behavior  1 Peter 1:15 NASB

So, the assumption that sin is actually good is invalid.

Comment: Maybe he is asking, what different does it make, both the sinner and the "holy" will go to Heaven with this understanding no?

Comment: @user1361315 Perhaps so.  To that I would say the godliness holds promise for both the present life, and the life to come... or at least Paul said that.  1 Timothy 4:7-8

Comment: the questioner is focusing on being a bad person, and not a good person.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Jesus die for our sins, see, consider darkness (total absence of light), consider the truth (total absence of lie), but we you light up a candle, the darkeness disappear. Those are two things that cannot co-exist. As many others examples in our world, we will find out that they are laws (physical, chemical, ...). God's nature (even this expression make no sense but i will skip the subject) is incompatible with the desobience to His will, just like the darkness and the candlelight, so something happened that make humans incompatible with the communion of God (remember before Adam's sin, God use to come in the garden and share time with Adam, Adam can contemplate God's nature, like the need for our body to be provided some vitamin D and if you don't receive that sunlight for a long you will start feeling depressed, Adam use to comtemplate God's nature), but since the sin the nature of Adam has changed. Proof is : imagine, God has created Adam and know every atom (if that was what he was made of) of his body. But after consuming the "fruit", when Adam hear the voice of God, coming to visit him as usual, that time he has been SCARED, he HIDE, and says : "I hide from you because i am NAKED", because of JUDGEMENT, and SHAME. God has created him and knows every atom of his body but he is trying to hide that body from God. Do you understand ? Something has corrupted his jugdement, he can no longer realize the "nature" of God (he think he can hide things from God, which means he don't understand the "nature" of God, and now he know new feelings (FEAR, SHAME, CRITISCISM) the roots of our troubles on earth. What FEAR can you can you have when the one who provide and take care of you is GOD who has created all the univers and more.

So through our birth in Adam, we receive that nature in inheritance which cannot understand and trust God and made us incompatible with God.

What Jesus did is provide a  mean by which we die, with the whole universe witnessing, for our sins in the death of Jesus, and we reborn as new nature compatible with God in the resurrection of Jesus. So that is a contract between God and us, and we sign that contract by believing in this contract (FAITH) and proving by asking the baptism in Jesus's death and resurrection, the whole universe witnessing. THIS is why Jesus die for our sins.

As you understand the nature of Adam before the sin, know that our new nature in Christ hate the things God hates naturally and so does not commit the things the 10 commandements have called sins. And this is a natural process, not a forcing. And watch, some people nowadays call everything sin and drown believers under seas of guilt, which is the human mind naturally tendencies more than a spiritual fact. For remember, we are saved by Grace through faith, not as a product of our non-commited sins (actions). Still, having the Holy-Spirit of God in you, teaches you the hate (not a sin) of what God dislike (dislike not who but what, not the sinner but the sin). Then, **if you're a born again christian**, **baptised with belief** in the death and resurection of Jesus, do as you feel the conviction by the Holy-Spirit. be bless

Answer (score 1):

No.  Jesus did not die so we could sin as much as we want. Romans 5;19  For as by one man's disobedience many were made sinners, so by the obedience of one shall many be made righteous. What is sin ?  1 John 3;4 Whosoever committeth sin transgresseth  the law: for sin is transgression of the law.  What law?  God's law, the ten commandments. Exodus 20; 3-18   3 Thou shalt have no other gods before me. C1  4 Thou shalt not make unto thee any graven image, or any likeness of any thing that is in heaven above or that is in the earth beneath, or that is in the water under the earth. 5 Thou shalt not bow down thyself to them, nor serve them: for I the LORD thy God am a jealous God, visiting the iniquity of the fathers upon the children unto the third and forth generation of them that hate me; 6 And shewing mercy unto thousands of them that love me, and keep my commandments. C2  7 Thou shalt not take the name of the LORD thy God in vain; for the LORD will not hold him guiltless that taketh his name in vain. C3  8. Remember the sabbath day to keep it holy. 9 Six days shalt thou labour and do all thy work: 10 But the seventh day is the sabbath of the LORD thy God: in it thou shalt not do any work, thou, nor thy son, nor thy daughter, thy manservant, nor thy maidservant, nor thy cattle, nor thy stranger that is within thy gates: 11  For in six days the LORD made heaven and earth, the sea and all that is in them is, and rested the seventh day: wherefore the LORD blessed the sabbath day, and hallowed it.  C4  12 Honour thy father and thy mother: that thy days may be long upon the land which the LORD thy God giveth thee.  C5  13 Thou shalt not kill.  C6  14 Thou shalt not commit adultery.  C7  15 Thou shalt not steal. C8  16 Thou shalt not bear false witness against thy neighbour.  C9  17 Thou shalt not covet thy neighbour's house, thou shalt not covet thy neighbour's wife, nor his manservant, nor his maidservant, nor his ox, nor his ass, nor anything that is thy neighbour's.  C 10  James 2;10  For whosoever shall keep the whole law , and yet offend in one point, he is guilty of all.   Hebrews 10;26 For if we sin wilfully after that we have received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice for sins.   Revelation 22;14 Blessed are they that do his commandments, that they may have right to the tree of life, and may enter in through the gates into the city.